# Style sheet could not be loaded

Tags: http, crystal-lang

I'm trying to write a simple website using crystal. I've got a folder called `assets` with `index.html`, `style.css`, and a couple of images.

When I try to load the site I can access `index.html`, but nothing else works. Firefox reports an error for style.css, and says the images are corrupted.

**Server.cr**

```
require "http/server"

class LieServer

    def initialize(p : Int)
        port = p
        @server = HTTP::Server.new("127.0.0.1", port, [
        HTTP::ErrorHandler.new,
        HTTP::LogHandler.new,
        HTTP::CompressHandler.new,
        ]) do |context|
            resp = context.response
            if context.request.path == "/" && context.request.method == "GET"
                resp.content_type = "text/html"

                File.open("./assets/index.html") do |file|
                    IO.copy(file, resp)
                end
            elsif (context.request.path == "/assets/sad.jpg" || context.request.path == "/assets/fireworks.jpg")
                resp.content_type = "image"
            elsif context.request.path == "/assets/style.css"
                resp.content_type = "text/css"
            else
                resp.respond_with_error(message = "/", code = 404)
            end
        end
    end

    def start
        puts "listening on http://localhost:#{@server.port}"
        @server.listen
    end
end
```

**Firefox:**

[image]

Comment: try a stylesheet validator like this one https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: I had to make some changes, but now despite the CSS being valid, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You only serve the file in the first route for `assets/index.html`. All the other `elsif` clauses don't open a file and copy it to the response.

Comment: Additionally, I'd recommend having a look at http://kemalcr.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually copying the css file over in response. Just setting up the content type. Try changing the css elsif block to:

```
elsif context.request.path == "/assets/style.css"
       resp.content_type = "text/css"
       File.open("./assets/style.css") do |file|
         IO.copy(file, resp)
       end
 else
 .
 .
 .
```

By the way your images are running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are serving only index.html, for other files you are just changing content type.

You can use Shivneri framework for this. Shivneri provides inbuilt file server.

### How to configure

```
Shivneri.folders = [{
    path: "/",
    folder:  File.join(Dir.current, "assets"),
}]
```

for more info take a look at file server doc - https://shivneriforcrystal.com/tutorial/file-server/